# Windows DeleteFile Fails

Tags: windows

My problem is the Windows DeleteFile function fails even after many attempts. For our Beta testing we are looking at something around a 10% failure rate. The loop waits up to 5 seconds and today was our first failure after implementing multiple waits and counts. I am unable to open the file with the delete on close because I'm not sure if I can delete the file until and SQL transaction completes correctly. The DeleteFile function retrieves the entire path and file name so it's not as if a directory switch is causing an issue.

TIA

```
int count = 1;
bool IsDeleted = false;

while ((IsDeleted == false) && (count <= 50))
{
    if (count > 1)
    {
        if (maxcount < count)
            maxcount = count;
        Sleep(100);
    }
    IsDeleted = DeleteFile(ProgramDataFolder + sr.Name);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Why is the function failing?

Comment: Are you checking the error condition that occurs when `DeleteFile` returns `false`?

Comment: Do you have an active antivirus software? I noticed it tends to jump on newly created files...

Comment: I believe it's an Access error but why anti-virus would have the file open 5 seconds I have no idea. I have to add code to get last error to be sure. Normally, 90-95% of the time the function passes on the first attempt. But it seems when the function fails waiting 5 seconds doesn't help.

Comment: "I have to add code to get last error to be sure" **yes**. Do that please and report the results. Use Process Explorer to see who's got the file open.

Comment: Use process monitor with path substring filter to your file and select the Drop Filtered Events in the menu to keep the memory footprint low. Now when the problem occurs again you can see who has opened the file and not closed it yet directly with call stacks.

Comment: unfortunately, it's not so easy to use the process explorer because it's something that doesn't happen locally. it's only happening at some end users. Is there a Windows function to find out which process has the handle open programmatically?

Comment: handles.exe from sysinterals lists all open handles which includes file handles. You can pipe its output to a file and get it from your customers. You can embedd handles.exe as resource and unpack it at runtime to get the required infos. Please not that this does violate the license of sysinternals but for diagnostics purposes and not a full released software it should be ok.

Comment: Whatever process you are going to find, your user isn't going to let you kill or uninstall it.  You are not telling us anything to help us help you, punt this problem by *moving* the file instead.  To the recycle bin, call SHFileOperation.